# How does one create a div that extends to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

If you notice the main page of twitter has a div that always extends to the bottom of the page.  I inspected the CSS and it looked like they where using

```
min-height:100%
```

However, this did not work when I tested it in a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/z5qVh/1/)

How do I create a div that always extends to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll also want to ensure that your body and html have 100% height as well.

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Well, in short, the element that you would like to be 100% height inherits its height from its parents - html and body. Since they don't have a height set by default, you have to set them to 100% yourself in order for it to work.

Comment: So html contains body contains div.  Thanks.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist Note that if you have long pages, setting min-height instead is usually preferred.  Otherwise, you'll have things like the background from the html/body elements not extending all the way to the bottom of the content.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using `height:100%;`.  Also note, height 100% needs to be set to the parent container. In this case `html,body { }`

If `html,body { }` is not set to 100% then the container inside will only stretch 100% of it's container height.

http://jsfiddle.net/z5qVh/2/

```
 html,body {
        height:100%;
    }
    #all{
        height: 100%;
        background: #ff0000;
    }
```